# SQL Report Builder 3.0 Mesclar Linhas em uma coluna de Totalizador

Tags: c#, sql, relatório, report-builder

Considerando uma consulta simples onde traga uma lista de pessoas contendo seu nome, código e sua idade, gostaria que fosse exibido na ultima coluna da direita a soma das idades conforme a imagem (nesse exemplo considero como se cada um tivesse 15 anos) [image: tabela ideal]

utilizando grupos até consigo mas o grupo sempre fica no inicio da tabela (lado esquerdo) gostaria que ficasse do lado direito, tem uma opção de inverter a orientação da tabela, mas fica como se fosse espelhado eu teria que inverter a posição dos campos para que ficasse próximo do ideal entretanto isso para uma futura manutenção ficaria difícil de compreender, gostaria de saber se há uma solução mais simples, talvez com uma expressão

Answer (score 0):

Uma solução :

```
SELECT NOME,
       CODIGO,
       (SELECT SUM(IDADE) FROM TABELA) SOMA_IDADE
FROM TABELA
```

Alguns BDs ANALYTIC FUNCTIONS que facilitam tarefas deste tipo.

Comment: Então, trazer o valor somado eu ja faço, o problema é fazer no report builder a exibição ser feita da forma que eu exemplifiquei na imagem

Answer (score 0):

Esse comportamento de mesclagem no R.Builder você faz na construção do relatório, colocando na seção inferior do painel chamada "Grupo de Linhas" os campos que serão "mesclados". Dessa forma , considerando o seu exemplo, seu campo de soma = 60 será apresentado sem repetições ao arrastar o mesmo na seção "Grupo de Linhas" no layout de construção.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/lTpwE.png